# How to authenticate user login and pass JWT token using spring boot, jpa,hibernate and mysql

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-services, spring-boot

I am working on angular application which has login form(username and password). I have to build REST APi endpoint which authenticates the credentails against database values and sends back JWT to the angular client. I am using spring boot,jpa,hibernate and mysql and I am not sure how to authenticate the login crendentails and send back JWT. Can anyone please advise on how it has to be done.

UserController.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.sambasoft.entities.User;
import org.sambasoft.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders="*")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/{UserID}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable Integer UserID) {
        return userRepository.findOne(UserID);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/user/{UserID}")
    public boolean deleteUser(@PathVariable Integer UserID) {
        userRepository.delete(UserID);
        return true;
    }

    @PutMapping("/user")
    public User updateUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @PostMapping("/user")
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

User.java

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     @Column(name = "UserID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer UserID;

    private String Username;
    private String Password;

    public Integer getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
        UserID = userID;
    }

    public User(String Username, String Password)
    {
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Password = Password;       
    }

    public User() {

    }
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CrudBackendApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrudBackendApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please go through one of Spring's numerous tutorials, like [this one](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/).

Comment: I dont see the user validation against database , Can you please any example program or something in detail which explains things to be done

Answer (score 0):

You should use Spring Security (SprSec) which is a prime framework to implement authentication and authorization in your Java app.

SprSec provides an authentication framework that supports Username/passord with either browser based BasicAuthentication or with generated login form as well as other authentication paradigm such as Open Id Connect pre-authentication. SprSec is also highly customizable providing that you invest significant amount of time in reading and learning it's capabilities.

SprSec offers an extensive AutoConfiguration capability that adapts to your application context by discovering the configured libraries on your classpath. From what I see from your code, you will probably be able to address your needs with little configuration. I would advise you though to use a 4.x version that allows superseeding some AutoConfiguration settings while version 5 will automaticallyremove all AutoConfiguration settings as soon as you create a configuration object (WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class in this case) and leave you to setup the whole shebang. After a while, you'll certainly be able to but as a starting endeavor, it could be quite challenging.

https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/

As for the JWT, there are many libraries that you can use to generate and validate tokens. Their capabilities can be easily integrated in the SprSec Authentication and Authorization process through inserting servlet Filters in the SprSec SecurityFilterChain (or you can derive from one of the many provided SprSec filters).

Browse to https://jwt.io/  ...

and scroll down past the JWT debugger. You will find an extensive list of such libraries (6 in java). I personnally favour Nimbus-jose-jwt for it's excellent documentation and their extensive coverage of the standard.

In conclusion, I strongly recommend you to invest the time to use SprSec as your approach is about re-inventing a very, very complex wheel instead of reusing an existing sophisticated wheel that has been developped by highly knowledgeable specialists.

Hope this helps.

Jake

Answer (score -1):

You could use spring security! if that helps you

Comment: This is better served as a comment than an answer.

Comment: Can't, low rep. Sorry :)

Comment: Ok, in that case can you expand your answer a bit with some reference links, sample code etc? Then it can become a proper answer.